# How to change ownership of a given directory before restarting a service

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, cron

I am trying to write a script that I will place in cron job.

The script is going to check every 5 minutes if the process is running if not it has to start the process but my problem is that while the process start it is owned by root and that changes some files in a specific directory so, I wanted to make the script start the service then wait for 10 sec and stop the service, after that it will go to the specific directory and change the ownership all all the files in that directory and then the script will start the service again.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Here is what I came up with so far. The script works to start and stop the service but it times out when the service stop and does not change any ownership in the given directory

```
#!/bin/bash
exec_start="sudo systemctl start new-service"
exec_stop="sudo systemctl stop new-service"
check1=/root/testing/
username="user1"
process="new-service"

changing_ownership () {
cd $check1 && /usr/bin/chown $username:$username *
}

startAndStop(){
/usr/bin/sudo su - user1 && $exec_start &
 sleep 10 && $exec_stop &
 sleep 2 && exit
}

startAgain(){
/usr/bin/sudo su - user1 && $exec_start &
sleep 5 && exit
}

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
 echo "running"
 exit

else
 echo "Not running...Going to start the service"
 startAndStop
 changing_ownership
 startAgain
fi

exit
```

Here is the content of /root/testing/

```
[root@server2 ~]# cd -
/root/testing
[root@server2 testing]# ll
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 24 21:34 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 24 21:34 file2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 24 21:34 file3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 24 21:39 file8888
```

Thanks

Comment: Do the files need to be root-owned during that first startup, or is it okay if chown happens every time the service starts?

Comment: So the main issue is that every time that I restart the service, if am root while restarting the service, it override the ownership of certain files however, those files need to be own by user1 (for example) so the service can be owned by user1 and not root.

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems I see.

I made a simple test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
startAndStop(){
        echo "Start 1" &
        echo "Sleep 2" && echo "Stop 3"
        echo "Sleep 4" && exit
}
startAndStop
echo "Rest of Script"
```

This simulates the startAndStop function of your program.

Here's the output:

```
$ bash test.sh
Sleep 2
Stop 3
Sleep 4
Start 1
```

Two points about this function:

1. Things execute out of order. The single `&` backgrounds the start task. Are you sure you wanted to do that? Wouldn't you want to wait for the process to complete starting to stop it? I know you put `sleep`s in, but waiting for it to exit is better, I think. Things could get very strange if the command didn't finish in time.
2. Notice how it didn't print `Rest of Script`. The `exit` command doesn't exit the function, it exits the entire script.

You have `/usr/bin/sudo su - user1 && $exec_start`. I don't think that is what you wanted to do. You set `exec_start="sudo systemctl start new-service"`. So what you end up doing is switching to user1 and then elevating to root permissions to start the service. New script, on my machine. `$(pwd)` will print the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - user1 && /usr/bin/sudo echo $(pwd)
```

Let's execute it:

```
[root]$ bash test.sh
[user1]$
```

I got a shell! The `&&` *waits the completion* of the previous command - namely `sudo su -`, which gives a root shell. The `echo` command was not executed until I left the shell:

```
[user1]$ exit
logout
/root
[root]$
```

Even then, it gave the `/root` directory, not `/home/user1`. This is definatly not what you wanted. How about adding this script to crontab to run *as the user*? This would be root's crontab line:

```
 */5      *       * * *   user1    /home/user1/new-service-watch.sh
```

That way, you wouldn't have to mess with double-switch-user-ing. The script will be started by `cron` as `user1`, then you just need to `sudo` so you can run `systemctl` and you keep everything else as that user.

Here's a quick idea. Please don't use as-is!!!!

*edit: changing script to start service as user1, per request. removed `$sudo_cmd` from the `exec_start` and `exec_stop` definitions.*

*edit2: chowning should use `sudo` in case the files are owned by root. Also, stopping the service should use `sudo` just in case root had started the process.`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo_cmd="/usr/bin/sudo" # these are just my paths, change as needed
chown_cmd="$sudo_cmd /usr/bin/chown" # added sudo
systemctl_cmd="/bin/systemctl"
date_cmd="/bin/date"
# if define process before exec_start & exec_stop, 
# you can use it in your exec_start & exec_stop definitions
process="new-service"
exec_start="$systemctl_cmd start $process" # don't sudo so it runs as user1
exec_stop="$sudo_cmd $systemctl_cmd stop $process" # added sudo
check1="/root/testing"
username="user1"
log_file="/var/log/new-service-watch.log" # why not log things? :)

# putting the entirety of the execution in 
# braces lets you pipe it somewhere easily
{ # start_brace
changeOwnership()
{
    echo "$($date_cmd) Changing ownership"
    # there is no need to change directory
    # because we will use '-R' to be recursive
    $chown_cmd -R $username:$username $check1
}

startService()
{
    echo "$($date_cmd) Starting $process"
    $exec_start
    sleep 5
}

stopService()
{
    echo "$($date_cmd) Stopping $process"
    $exec_stop
    sleep 5
}

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
    echo "$($date_cmd) Running...No action needed."
else
    echo "$($date_cmd) Not running...Going to start the service."
    startService
    stopService
    changeOwnership
    startService
fi
} >> "$log_file" # end_brace
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I really like the way you made the script simple. I  still have some concerns. 1) How about adding this script to crontab to run as the user? So I have to do it in the root crontab or the user's crontab. Like crontab -u user1 -e?? 2) My other concern is after the file ownership changed and the service has been restarted it is still showing as owned by root and not user1. Is just like it was root who start the service. That is why in my previous script I tended to switch as user1 before starting the service.

Comment: 1) You can do it either way. The way I listed was adding it to root's crontab to run as user1. You could also add it to user1's crontab. Both will result in the same result. 2) Does user1 have permission to start the service? If you log in as user1 and do a `systemctl start new-process` does it start correctly? The reason I ask is most time a user is not able to start and stop a service.

Comment: 1) Makes sense. 2) Yes the user1 has the permission to start the service. If user1 start the servicve it shows on the ps faux that it is owned by user1 but if root start it, automatically it is owned by root and root will change the ownership of these files in /root/testing dir

Comment: 1) Joy. 2) Ok, then simple fix. editing the script now.

Comment: Whoops! Just realized the chown needs to be sudo-d

Comment: And the service stop should be sudo-d in case root started it before.

Comment: Now I am little confused lol.. instead of sudo_cmd="/usr/bin/sudo" it should be sudo_cmd="/usr/bin/sudo -ed"? Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry. "sudo"-d as in made to use sudo. Ignore my massacering of the english language. I changed it in the scripts. Proper english: The chown command needs to run with sudo so it can change files made by root. The service stop command needs to run with sudo so it can stop a service started by root. Changes made.